# 'OpenSeadragon' import call expects exactly one argument issue on Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, angular8, openseadragon

I'm having an issue with my website not loading on Safari and getting an error message

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'OpenSeadragon'. import call
> expects exactly one argument.

This issue only appears to be happening in Safari (seen both on iPhone and iMac) and not an issue on Chrome or Firefox.

When I click on the error message it takes me to a `main.min.js` file that was downloaded from `cdn.jsdelivr.net`. I'm not an expert in web development so I'm not sure what's wrong with the lines that are highlighted, and also don't know how I'd modify this file anyway, since I don't deliver the file.

[image]

These are the relevant lines for how I'm including OpenSeadragon into my website in my `index.html` file.

[image]

Any help that can be provided would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using [ES6 source file](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/openseadragon-annotations@1.0.5/src/main.min.js) instead of [output bundle](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/openseadragon-annotations@1.0.5/dist/openseadragon-annotations.js) for `openseadragon-annotations` npm package.

Chrome and Firefox were smart enough to pick up ES6 module syntax automatically, but you were supposed to use the output bundle file.

According to the Webpack build [configuration](https://github.com/Emigre/openseadragon-annotations/blob/4653efa77f15eacaf2bd75c22346300733301281/webpack.config.babel.js#L27-L28) the output file is `dist/openseadragon-annotations.js`.

Try replacing `src/main.min.js` with `dist/openseadragon-annotations.js` like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/openseadragon@2.4/build/openseadragon/openseadragon.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/openseadragon-annotations@1.0.5/dist/openseadragon-annotations.js"></script>
```